# Spring Boot REST · Can't exclude a repository without excluding a controller

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to exclude a repository from component scan. However, the four things I tried that works also exclude a controller, which I don't want. Here's what I have:

#### Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.project")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.project.model" })
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.project.repository")
public class Application extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
}
```

#### SaleItemController.java

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class SaleItemController {
    ...
}
```

#### SaleItemRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "saleItem", path = "saleItems", excerptProjection = SaleItemProjection.class)
public interface SaleItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SaleItem, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SaleItem> {}
```

First attempt: filters on `Application`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.project")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.project.model" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.project.repository" }, excludeFilters={@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=SaleItemRepository.class)})
public class Application extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
}
```

Second attempt: conditional element on `SaleItemRepository`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "saleItem", path = "saleItems", excerptProjection = SaleItemProjection.class)
@ConditionalOnExpression("false")
public interface SaleItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SaleItem, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SaleItem> {}
```

Third attempt:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "SaleItem", path = "saleItems", excerptProjection = SaleItemProjection.class)
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SaleItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SaleItem, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SaleItem> {}
```

Fourth attempt: read somewhere that include filters have precedence over exclude filters:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project", includeFilters={@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=SaleItemController.class)})
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.project.model" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.project.repository" }, excludeFilters={@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=SaleItemRepository.class)})
public class Application extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
}
```

(placing the `includeFilters` together with `excludeFilters` throws an exception because it can't find another repository)

All attempts successfully exclude the repository, but also exclude the controller, which I don't want. I know the repository has been excluded because some things *don't* break when it's excluded and I know the controller has been excluded because an endpoint mapped in it stops working.

How do I exclude only the repository?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it. It seems to be working with `exported = false` on `SaleItemRepository`'s `@RepositoryRestResource`. Plus, I removed `excerptProjection = SaleItemProjection.class`.

Now I have other things to fix...